# Set hashMap's value

Tags: java, hashmap

I am using drools workbench and I have trouble setting a hashmap. I want to avoid adding a method just to add values to the map so I am trying to find a workaround.

When I need to set the value of a list I use:

```
setList(Arrays.asList("string one", "string two", ...));
```

I was wondering if such a method exists for hashmaps.

Comment: Are you going to add <Key, Value> pair, or just values.. ?

Comment: <Key, Value> pair that's why I use a HashMap.

Comment: In drools workbench I need to use guided rules and avoid free DRL form so I can't use .put method. I will either add a method that actually implements .put or I will find something like Arrays.asList that I mentioned before to be able to use its setter.

Comment: As HashMap works on <Key, Value>, it is not possible to add values without Key. However, you can use other collections like ArrayList or Set based on your requirement.

Comment: I do have keys so a map is what I need. It's not a matter of which data structure I need to use but how to populate it without using .put method.

Comment: As a side note: don't try to avoid extra methods.

Comment: Tbh I just created a method to be able to do my work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use Map, then definitely you should store the data in from of **(Key, Value)** pair. Now , in HashMap, you have two methods to store data,

```
 1. put(Object any) - This method takes single object. 
 2. putAll(Map otherMap) - This method takes some other map, and will add all the elements of that map to yours one.
```

So If these methods are not suitable for you, then I think you should write your own method to add values. May be you can write as below.

```
class DroolMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V> {

    public DroolMap() {
        super();
    }
    public DroolMap(int size) {
        super(size);
    }

    public DroolMap<K, V> add(K key, V value) {
        this.put(key, value);
        return this;
    }
}

class TestDroolMap {
    public void testDroolMap() {
        DroolMap<String, String> droolMap = new DroolMap<String, String>();
         // You can add as many <Key, Value> pairs in one line
        droolMap.add("k1", "v1").add("k2", "v2").add("k3", "v3");
    }
}
```

Comment: I could do something like that but as I said I am trying to find another solution if there is any to find.

Comment: Ohhk, I got your point, but I don't see any built-in methods in HashMap to ful fill the requirement, I think you have to write your own.. :(

Comment: I think so too. I already did it so if anything interesting comes up I'll change it and inform this post as well.

Comment: yess sure,,It will great to know ,,,,I will also try to search more on this, and If I will get something,, will post here.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use 3rd party libs you can use Guava's ImmutableMap

```
Map<String, String> test = ImmutableMap.of("k1", "v1", "k2", "v2");
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do not think this would be easier in the workbench than just implementing a simple add function. That is what I am trying to avoid.